# Find the center of mass and moment of inertia with respect to the z-axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the center of mass and moment of inertia with respect to the z-axis ofthe solid in the first octant bounded by the graphs: $z = x^2 + y^2$, *y = x*, and *y* = 2; with density proportional to the distance from the *yz*-plane.

I am having a hard time understanding what $\rho$(*x, y, z)* is as the problems that I usually do $\rho$(*x, y, z)* is usually given. Similarly, I am having a hard time of calculating what the bounds are for *Q*. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should check those bounds because they don't enclose a finite region

Answer (score 0):

The problem states that the density is proportional to the distance from the $yz$-plane.  This is simply $\rho(x,y,z) = kx$ for some constant $k$.  Moments of inertia are usually defined as

$$
I_* \;\; =\;\; \int_0^2 \int_0^x \int_0^{x^2+y^2} (*)\rho(x,y,z) dz dxdy
$$

where $* =x,y,z$.  The centroid is then a vector $(c_x, c_y, c_z)$ where

$$
(c_x,c_y,c_z) \;\; =\;\; \frac{(I_x, I_y, I_z)}{M}
$$

where $M = \iiint \rho(x,y,z) dxdydz$ is the total mass of the object.